# Django Reverse for '' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django

I have  form that has been generated by django and i'm trying to return an object id with the form to the function.

I received this error .I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work cause picture id is valid id and the regex of the URL should capture it and return it to my functions unless the current URL must match because my current  URL for the page is is 1:8000/comment/1/

```
Reverse for 'world.CommentCreator' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

File "C:\o\17\mysite\pet\views.py" in CommentCreator
  269.     return render(request,'commentcreator.html',   {'comment':comment,'picture':p,'search':CommentsForm()})
```

My views.py

```
def CommentCreator(request,picture_id):
    p = Picture.objects.get(pk=picture_id)
    comment = Comment.objects.filter(picture=p)

    return render(request,'commentcreator.html',    {'comment':comment,'picture':p,'search':CommentsForm()})
```

My URL.py

```
    url(
        r'^comment/(?P<picture_id>\d+)/$',
        'pet.views.CommentCreator',
        name = 'CommentCreator',
    ),
```

Html

```
 {% if picture.image  %}
 {% endif %}
 <ul>           
    <br><img src="{{ picture.image.url }}">

    </ul>

 {% for c in comment %}
     {% ifequal c.picture.id picture.id %}

 <br>{{ c.body }}</li>
 <br>{{ c.created}}</li>
 <br>{{ c.user}}</li>
     {% endifequal %}

 {% endfor %}

 <br><br><br><br>

 {% if picture %}
 <form method = "post" action"{% url world.CommentCreator picture.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{search}}
    <input type ="submit" value="Search "/>
 </form>

 {% endif %}
```

Comment: try quoting and using the name you gave it  `{% url 'CommentCreator' picture.id %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `.` instead of `:` in the url

```
<form method = "post" action"{% url world.CommentCreator picture.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

It must be

```
<form method = "post" action"{% url world:CommentCreator picture.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the url name in url tag:

```
{% url CommentCreator picture.id %}
```

That's it, single quote around url name is not necessary if you are on django < 1.3. It still work in django 1.4 but it is deprecated and it is completely remove in django 1.5.

For future compatibility you should use this [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) if on django < 1.5:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url 'CommentCreator' picture.id %}
```

For the named capturing group URL's it is not necessary to pass URL params as keywords or args, both will work (but it is important to know the order, that is why keywords params are more preferable in URL tag):

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url 'CommentCreator' picture.id %}
{% url 'CommentCreator' picture_id=picture.id %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL configuration uses keyword arguments for the CommentCreator view, supply them to `url` as such:

```
{% url 'CommentCreator' picture_id=picture.id %}
```

Comment: i get this error Reverse for 'world.CommentCreator' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'picture_id': 1}' not found. Does the current URL have to match with Commentcreator URL?

Comment: Fixed - you need quotes around it, and then can just refer to the view by name.